# I'm trying to add images to my flickity carousel from an array and using a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

adding cell elements to the main carousel.
Having trouble what to put in the img tag

```
for (let i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {    
    $('.main-carousel').each(function(){

        $(this).append("<div class='carousel-cell'><img 
        src='imageArray???'</div>");
  });
}
```

Comment: provide all code before you get downvoted add your html that is used for the carousel

Comment: Can you add a line console.log(imageArray[i]); and post back to the question one of the objects that is logged to the console?  One we see what is available in that object?  It should be pretty easy to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var imageArray = ['imageURL1.png', 'imageURL2.png', 'imageURL3.png'];

for (let i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {    
    $('.main-carousel').each(function() {

        $(this).append('<div class='carousel-cell'><img 
        src="'+imageArray[i]+'"></div>');
  });
}
```